# Get parents child pages

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu, php

I have this code:

```
<?php

    global $post;

    $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 )
    { 
        // Is subpage
        // Here I want to get all sibling from the current page
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Is no subpage
        if( count( $children ) == 0 ) 
        {
            // Has no children
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Has children
            echo '<div class="subnav-header">';
            echo '<div class="subnav-table">';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($children as $child){ ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child->guid; ?>"><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }

?>
```

First, it detects if the current page is a subpage, or normal page. When the page is a subpage, I want to display all the sibling pages of the current page just like I did if the page is no subpage, and has children.

---

So, in short, what I want to do is this:

- When the current page is a subpage, check if the page has any siblings.
- If the page has sibling, display them in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, and decided I could best post my answer here, since people can learn from it :)

```
<?php


    global $post;

    $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );
    $siblings = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->post_parent ) );

    // or, if you want to exclude the current page:
    // $siblings = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->post_parent, 'exclude' => $post->ID ) );

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 )
    { 
        // Is subpage
        if( count( $siblings ) == 0 )
        {
            // Has no siblings
        }
        else
        {
            // Has siblings
            echo '<div class="subnav-header">';
            echo '<div class="subnav-table">';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($siblings as $sibling){ ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $sibling->guid; ?>"><?php echo $sibling->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Is no subpage
        if( count( $children ) == 0 ) 
        {
            // Has no children
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Has children
            echo '<div class="subnav-header">';
            echo '<div class="subnav-table">';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($children as $child){ ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child->guid; ?>"><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }

?>
```